# why there is two tokens Access and ID in OpenID Connect

Tags: openid, openid-connect

Why there are two tokens in Open ID connect authentication. What is the exact use of ID token. when would i use that. Mainly external authentication are used to get access to particular features. Can some

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of each token is different :

The access token authorize your client to get resources by sending requests to a resource server.

The ID Token authenticates the resource owner. It contains a set of claims that depend on the authorization request you sent.